# How to programmatically fetch billing details for a GCP VM instance?

Tags: python, rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I went through the GCP documentation and couldn't find much details. The docs talk about exporting the billing information and using it but that requires certain IAM permissions that I do not have. Is there an API way of fetching the bill/invoice details?

Answer (score 0):

These are all the APIs related to billing [[1]](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/billing/cloudbilling/v1/). As you can see there, they require certain IAM permissions that you may not have.

If you want, you can estimate pretty accurately the cost of a GCE VM [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing) using the calculator [[3]](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/).

Comment: Thanks. The billing APIs (1) do not provide a mechanism to find billing details for a VM. (2) and (3) can help me predict the cost of a VM but not determine the bill incurred for a VM.

Comment: Those are all the options there are, apart from [exporting the billing data](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-file) (but you said you can't do that due to IAM permissions). Anyway, if you know how many time the VM was on (you can log it, for example), that should be enough to know how much it was.